# Setting up akka in playframework, how to configure and get hold of ActorSystem?

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

I'm trying to create a simple akka setup in my play application.

```
import akka.actor._
import akka.event.Logging
class HelloActor extends Actor with ActorLogging{
  def receive = {
    case "hello" => log.info("hello received")
    case _ => log.info("catch call received")
  }
}
```

I have read that I should create my ActorSystem in global, but should I be creating a singleton to hold the reference?

```
Global.scala

override def onStart(app: Application) {
  // ???
}
```

I have a simple json endpoint in my play application, so whenever that api endpoint gets called I want to pass the message to my akka actor.

I am basically creating an akka system build around play so it can be sent messages over http.

```
// /testAkka/
def testAkka = Action(BodyParsers.parse.json) { request =>

    val message1Result = request.body.validate[Message1]
    message1Result.fold(
      errors => {
        BadRequest(Json.obj("status" -> "KO", "message" -> JsError.toFlatJson(errors)))
      },
       msg1 => {
         val helloActor = system.actorOf(Props(new HelloActor("Fred")), name = "helloactor")
         helloActor ! msg1.name
         Ok(Json.toJson(msg1))
       }
    )
  }
```

**Note:**
I don't want to use the default akka system in play, I need to create my own in application.conf

**How will should I create my ActorSystem in my onStart method in Global.scala and how will I reference this in my Controller?
Also, is there an example application.conf setup for play 2.2.3?
**

Comment: You cannot put it in the `Global` companion, initialize it in `onStart` and access it in all your controller classes? Of course, you can relocate `Global` in application.conf out of the default package in order to achieve that.

Comment: @kaktusito I am initializing it in onStart in Global.scala, that is wrong?

Comment: you can initialize it in onStart, that's alright. But you have to declare it outside the onStart method in order to be accessible from the controller classes.

Comment: @kaktusito that is what I was confused about, should I put it in a singleton object?

Comment: Ah, got it. Well, in the projects I have worked before, I usually put my own `ActorSystem` inside Global.scala (in case you don't want to use the default `ActorSystem` of Play) so I can use it from the controller classes. I don't create an additional singleton object to contain it. But if you need other kinds of global objects, then you may need to use dependency injection in order to ease the testing. Nonetheless, this is only my opinion :)

Comment: @kaktusito can you put a skeleton structure as an answer, that is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can define your `Global.scala` inside the `common` package as follows (it cannot be in the default package since you wouldn't be able to access that class):

```
import play.api._

package common

object Global extends GlobalSettings {

  val mySystem = ActorSystem("my-system")

  override def onStart(app: Application) {
    // initialize your stuff here
  }

}
```

Then you can use that system in your controllers as in:

```
def testAkka = Action(BodyParsers.parse.json) { request =>

    val message1Result = request.body.validate[Message1]
    message1Result.fold(
      errors => {
        BadRequest(Json.obj("status" -> "KO", "message" -> JsError.toFlatJson(errors)))
      },
       msg1 => {
         val helloActor = Global.mySystem.actorOf(Props(new HelloActor("Fred")), name = "helloactor")
         helloActor ! msg1.name
         Ok(Json.toJson(msg1))
       }
    )
  }
```

Finally, you have to tweak your `application.conf` and specify that your `Global.scala` is in a non-default location:

```
global=common.Global
```

Although I'm not very sure, if in Play 2.2.x you may have to write:

```
application.global=common.Global
```

Hope it helped )

Comment: I also have to define 'my-system' in my application.conf I am assuming, with the settings etc.  thanks!